# is it possible to combine 2 objects of class into one in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I am reading file that contains

```
Johh, 13, soccer, cricket
Mitchell, 14, cricket
Michael, 13, football, cricket, soccer
(all three in separate lines starting from names)
```

I have created class with objects called name, age and favourite sport. is it possible in C++ to combine stuff after age (which are favourite sports) into one object rather then having to write favourite sport1, favourite sport2 etc.
Example for John it can be student.getname() = john, student.getAge() = 13 and student.getFavSport = soccer,cricket. etc

really stuck at this part, have never been taught, any help would be appreciated Thank you

Comment: [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) might also be an alternative, as each favourite makes only sense once.

Comment: Thanks for reply, so like create vector for favourite sport and push_back favourite sports into it?

Comment: @ibrahimovich yes

Comment: `student.getAge() = 13` is not very idiomatic, consider using a setter like `void setage(int a) { age = a;}`

Comment: @anastaciu all good thanks

Comment: I tried to put it into a vector but it putting everything into it, how can I tell program to only store it after the age? thanks

Comment: @ibrahimovich: It sounds like you have running code, intended behavior, and different actual behavior. The 3 together are enough to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could go about this, as there are many containers. You could use a `std::vector`, and there are many tutorials on how to use them.

For this case, I would recommend using a `std::set`, which is defined in the header `<set>`.

Usage:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct Student { //I imagine your class looks like this
    std::string name;
    int age;
    std::set<std::string> FavSports;
};

int main() {
    Student MyStudent;
    MyStudent.FavSports.insert("soccer"); //insert
    MyStudent.FavSports.insert("cricket"); //insert
    MyStudent.FavSports.insert("football"); //insert

    bool Exists = MyStudent.FavSports.contains("soccer"); //also can use count() function, which returns 1 or 0. 0 for false, as none exist, 1 for true, as one does exist, and a set can have a max of one item of a same type.
    //Ex: a std::set can not contain two "cricket"s.

    auto Iterator = MyStudent.FavSports.find("cricket"); //get a set iterator Iterator that points to cricket

    std::string data = Iterator->data(); //get data of Iterator ("cricket")

    ++Iterator; //point to one forward

    for (std::string Element : MyStudent.FavSports) { //for each element in FavSports
        //do something with each element
    }

    MyStudent.FavSports.insert("football"); //already exists, does nothing

}
```

You may adapt this to your needs. More here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set